# ARKit CoreImage issue in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, arkit

I tried to to run this ARKit project from Github (https://github.com/StephenGuanqi/Unity-ARKit-Plugin), I fixed some issues 
there about some methods that were deprecated before building the project.

I tried to build the project again and I got an error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   `OBJC_CLASS_$_CIContext`...

After some research I found out that I should add **CoreImage** framework to my project, but I don't know where to put this and how.

Comment: What version is your Xcode?

Comment: Xcode version beta 9